# How Can I Convert JSON Data in HTML Table using Fetch (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

**Code:**

```js
 fetch("https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/locations", {
    method: 'get'
})
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.json()
            .then(
                function (data) {
                    document.write(dataTable(data));
                }
            )
    }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log('oops!');
});
```

I need to present JSON data in html table, here is a part of my code using fetch

Comment: JSON.stringify()?

Comment: Why dont you wanna use jQuery?

And here is an example of this being done with an AJAX Call and vanilla JS.
https://teamtreehouse.com/community/html-table-from-json-store-using-pure-javascript-no-jquery

Comment: What have you tried for the function `drawTable`? Can you show what you have tried and explain how it isn't working? Your fetch code looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, but I would use jQuery. It is more powerful, and it is solution "from the box".

Just include in your code. There are keys in your JSON that has array type value, so it is not clear what to do with them. In my example I just set it into *tablecell*.

```
function dataTable(object) {
    let keys = Object.keys(object[0]);

    let htmlColumns = '';
    keys.forEach((key) => htmlColumns += `<th>${key}</th>`);
    htmlColumns = `<tr>${htmlColumns}</tr>`;

    let htmlRows = '';
    object.forEach((row) => {
        let htmlRow = '';
        keys.forEach((key) => htmlRow += `<td>${row[key]}</td>`);
        htmlRow = `<tr>${htmlRow}</tr>`;

        htmlRows += htmlRow;
    });

    return `<table>
        ${htmlColumns}
        ${htmlRows}
    </table>`;
}
```

Comment: Nice to know it, Luiza. If my answer solved your question then you may select it as solution.